# Is there a PHP function like array_column that only returns single values?

Tags: php, arrays

I am looping through instances of associative arrays (these associative arrays themselves are part of an array).

For each array I want to return a value, based on a key.

Currently I have:

```
$image_path = array_column($myarray, 'uri');
```

But of course `array_column` stores its values in a array, which, considering it's only returning 1 value, is useless to me.

Is there an existing function that will allow me to just get a value based off a supplied key?

Eg:

```
$image_path = get_keys_value($myarray, 'uri');
```

Example array. This is a very basic example. The real thing has many levels to it:

```
$myarray = array
  (
    'instance' => array(
      'type' => 'somedata',
      'content' => somedata',
      'image' => array(
         'name' => 'photo',
         'uri' => 'path/to/file.png'
      ),
    ),
  );
```

Desired outcome:

$image_path contains 'path/to/file.png' string.

Comment: you means other than uri ?

Comment: Please share `$myarray` so that we can better understand

Comment: Also share the desired output

Comment: @Swapper no, I want to return the value that is associated with the key 'uri', eg: `uri => some/path/to/image.png`

Comment: @MeltingDog share your complete input array.

Comment: You means, ditto like array_column but key should be 'uri', is it ?

Comment: I want you to update your post with `print_r($myarray);`

Comment: @SahilGulati the real array is huge, with many levels, but here's a basic example.

Comment: Can you share that array in which you have 3-4 levels

Comment: `$myarray['instance']['image']['uri']` --  why do you need a function to get it?

Comment: @SahilGulati its a machine generated array with hundreds of items. I can't really type it all out and protect the clients identity sorry.

Comment: @axiac This is a good solution, but the array may change. There could be  3 layers, or 2.

Comment: @MeltingDog this fact is not visible in your question.

Comment: @MeltingDog, is my answer ok for you? I guess `array_map` will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
function array_column_recursive(array $haystack, $needle)
{
    $found = [];
    array_walk_recursive($haystack, function ($value, $key) use (&$found, $needle) {
        if ($key == $needle) {
            $found[] = $value;
        }
    });
    return $found;
}
echo array_column_recursive($myarray, 'uri')[0];
```

Here is working [code](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/acfbb4d2e532f0a2b49f28f78a53d5ff75902097).

array_column will work with only 2 level array structure.

Above array will solve your problem.

I hope this will help

Comment: Hmm I just get the error message 'cannot redeclare: array_column_recursive'

Comment: you may already have that function, do one thing rename it array_column_recursive1 and replace this name in calling code. and check

Comment: Weird, no matter what I name it it just says there's a problem with the line the echo is on as its already 'declared' on the line the function is on

Comment: echo array_column_recursive1($myarray, 'uri')[0]; you sure you did this ?

Comment: Yep I am. It just doesnt seem to like referring to the same function twice

Comment: are you using any framework ? because this is straight forward thing, give unique name to function and use it your way, thats it.

Comment: this is inside a Drupal hook, but surely that doesnt make any difference?

Comment: there are three places you need to make changes as the name of the function, once check again. 1. function call 2. function name 3. recursive function call.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can use [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php).

Ex:

```
$arr = [
    [
        'root' => [
            'child1' => [
                'child2' => 123
            ]
        ]
    ],
    [
        'root' => [
            'child1' => [
                'child2' => 456
            ]
        ]
    ],
    [
        'root' => [
            'child1' => [
                'child2' => 789
            ]
        ]
    ],
    [
        'root' => [
            'child1' => [
                'child2' => 123
            ]
        ]
    ],
];

print_r(array_map(function($row) {
    // here goes expression to get required path
    return $row['root']['child1']['child2'];
}, $arr));
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 123
    [1] => 456
    [2] => 789
    [3] => 123
)
```